# Symfony Deprecated Function

Tags: php, prototype, frameworks, symfony1

I have been using symfony for a few weeks now and I am using the online help a lot but the "Definite Guide To Symfony" seems to be very outdated. For example, I want to use the form helper function like the select_tag() function or the ajax form_remote_tag() function. However, these dont seem to exist anymore and I can only find their names in the deprecatedhelpers file. Does anyone know how I can use these functions? or are there updated names for these that I can use in the newest version of symfony?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "Definitive Guide to symfony" in "documentation" section since 1.3/1.4 release. Because it really **is** outdated. If you are newcomer, you should use [Practical symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/), [The symfony Reference Book](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/) and [More with symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/advent_calendar/) as a guide.

Next. You shouldn't use `select_tag()` — use symfony forms instead.

And finally, `form_remote_tag()` resides in `sfProtoculous` plugin. Just enable him in `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` (method `setup()`):

```
<?php
// ...skipped...
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    // ...skip...
    $this->enablePlugins(array('sfProtoculousPlugin'));
    // ...skip...
  }
```

et voilà!

Comment: Thanks!

Yes I am new to symfony. Could you give me a little more detail on how to active the sfProtoculous plugin? Do I need to download it first?